# I can not see with db Questoid SQLite Browser

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

i am using eclipse for android programing and now i need to view SQLite database in the emulator.
I followed these step:

Download .jar file

Place the plugin .jar file in your Eclipse plugins folder (e.g. /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins)

Restart Eclipse

Start up an Android Emulator w/ Debugging in Eclipse

Switch to the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse

Go to the 'File Explorer' tab to locate your device's database file

Navigate to: e.g. 'data -> data -> com.myproject -> databases -> myproject

Now when i try to Open the database file in Questoid i can't select it!
(see screen shot)
same advice?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

From your screen shot there, the database does not have a "." (read: period) in the file name & extension area.

Improper:  mydatabaseDB

Proper: mydatabase.db

Once the database shows the proper extension (and is a proper SQLite database), then Questoid will (I use the plugin all the time in Eclipse (Juno version)) then show the "active" button (not disabled like in your screen shot). When looking for latest database entries (what was just added into the database), I then click once again on the toolbar icon as you show there, in the upper right of the screen.  I then go to the Browse Data tab for that view, then choose the table from the database I want to view the fields from.

I hope this helps.

Happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with "sqlitemanager": only .db-Database files are accepted.

This is the solution:

1. Download this Questoid SqLiteBrowser: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/com.questoid/com.questoid.sqlitebrowser_1.2.0.jar.zip
2. Unzip and put it into eclipse/dropins (not Plugins)

Answer (score 0):

Try following these steps:

1) Close Eclipe

2) Remove the .jar from /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins.

3) Place the .jar in /eclipse/dropins and let Eclipse try to install it for you.

4) Start Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The file has to end with .db extension, so the answer is to name your database as this sqlite browser expects it to be. 
Another way of fixing it is to find a year old version that does not have this constraint.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use **sqlitebrowser** externally . You will have to pull your databse everytime from ddms though .

Answer (score -1):

Please use the extension ".db" in lowercase, please don't try with these extensions .SLQLITE, .BD, .DB, .SQL, or similar or without extensions.

Regards,